# Why socket.getservbyport(port) affect the output of socket.getservbyname(port)?

Tags: python

I tried to write a program similar to the nmap.
This part of the program is aimed to connect the port with UDP.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 result = s.connect_ex((target, portnum))
 if result == 0:
    socket.getservbyport(portnum)
    if verbose:
       print("%d/udp \t open " % portnum)
       udpports.append(portnum)
```

If I remove `socket.getservbyname(portnum)` ,all the port cannot use UDP.
I looked for it on the Internet and know that getservbyport isn't try to connect and find the service name of the port,it just find the service name from a table `/etc/service`.
So I'm confused why I couldn't get the right output once I deleted `socket.getservbyport(portnum)`.

Comment: You haven't shown us the rest of the code, and you haven't shown us the error.  We have no idea what the actual problem is...